# Does the SignalR RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); absolutely have to be put in Application_Start()?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, signalr, global-asax

Can it be put in other custom named methods within Global.asax that start up first like OnApplicationStarted()?  The dilemma I'm having is that our project has a custom class that the class in Global.asax is inheriting from instead of the standard "System.Web.HttpApplication".  Which means I can't use the "Application_Start" method to put my SignalR Hubs routing in.

So my question is this:  Is SignalR absolutely hardwired to use a method with the exact method name of "Application_Start" in the Global.asax?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MapHubs` simply creates the `signalr/hub` script. It doesn't matter where you generate it as long as it is generated before you attempt to use the script.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks.  So I think the issue I'm having boils down to the order jquery script references are being called...

Comment: It does alot more than generate the script. It makes SignalR's hubs work in general. It's the entry point for all signalr hub requests.

Comment: Oh, wow.  Just realized that you're David Fowler (the lead developer on the SignalR project).  I appreciate your answer on my issue with the signalr javascript.  It was spot on.  The problem was with the jquery library being loaded twice on the page.